# How long does it cost to retrieve all rows from a SQLite table?

Tags: sqlite

If I have one millions rows in a SQLite table, and I want to retrieve all of them. How long will this cost? Will it cost one millions times than only retrieve on row? If not, what is the correct way to retrieve all rows?

Comment: Show your database schema and your SQL requests in your question to provide some [mre]

Comment: You may benchmark a `SELECT *` against any table to get an idea of this.  Almost certainly fetching one million records does not take one million times as fetching one record, because any query has setup cost to fetch a connection, etc.